# How to remove decimals from the result in Distance API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Directions API can display the distance between two places. E. g.:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-draggable

However, that distance is displayed with decimals (e. g. `2520.359 km`). Is there a way to remove them (e. g. get the result of `2520 km`)?

Here is the part that should be responsible for it:

```
function computeTotalDistance(result) {
  var total = 0;
  var myroute = result.routes[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
    total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
  }
  total = total / 1000.
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total + ' km';
}
```

I thought that changing zeros would change the result, but it just breaks the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

```
document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = parseInt(total) + ' km';
```

Comment: It works. However, it always rounds the number to the smaller one - e. g. 10.9 will be 10 instead of 11. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: @take2 you can use `Math.ceil(total)`

Comment: @take2 I'm glad that I was able to help.